# Generate search results based on current object ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, comparator

I have asked something similar in the past but think I might have worded the question incorrectly.

I would like to know if it is possible in rails to take the current attribute via the show action of an object and then perform a search function against that attribute. For example

```
 def show
 @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
 end
```

Within the recipe model there is an attribute

```
:dish_name
```

This changes depending on which recipe I am looking at, so say i want to list recipes that are similar to the current dish_name being displayed on the show page, how would i go about this? just looking for some pointers in the right direction. I have had a look at solr but have decided to stick with ransack for my search functionality, though I cant see a way to achieve this in ransack.. has anyone written a method for something like this before?

BBC food do something similar, if not the same as what i want to achieve

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/easy_chocolate_cake_31070
```

if you look to the right hand side you will see a section called Related Recipes

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you actually need ransack for this, you can just use [`ActiveRecord`'s query methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions). I'd suggest creating an instance method `related_recipes` on `Recipe` which fetches related recipes, like this:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  def related_recipes

    # take the recipe's dish name and split it at spaces,
    # then wrap each item in the resulting array with '%'
    # to create SQL query terms.
    # e.g. "italian pasta" becomes ["%italian%", "%pasta%"]
    terms = dish_name.split(' ').map { |t| "%#{t}%" }

    # create a scope with all recipes except this one
    others = self.class.where('id != ?', id)

    # return all recipes other than this one that contain any of the terms
    # e.g. for the dish "italian pasta", this will become:
    # others.where('dish_name LIKE ? OR dish_name LIKE ?', '%italian%', '%pasta%')
    return others.where(terms.map { 'dish_name LIKE ?' }.join(' OR '), *(terms))
  end
```

Then in your `show` action, you can fetch the related recipes like this:

```
def show
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  @related_recipes = @recipe.related_recipes
end
```

You can display results by iterating over `@related_recipes`. I've commented the above heavily but if anything doesn't make sense please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so to get an understanding of what's going on here, terms = @recipe.dish_name.split('') will split the dish_name being displayed, so this will change every time dependent on the recipe id?

Comment: I've updated my answer, because I realized that you really don't need to use ransack for this type of thing.

Comment: To answer your question, `split` takes the `dish_name` for the recipe of the page you are on (`@recipe.dish_name`), and splits it at spaces, so "italian pasta" becomes the array `["italian", "pasta"]`. It then wraps each term in `%`s which in SQL language means "match anything which contains this term". Then you can pass that to `where` to get all *other* recipes which contain either term.

Comment: So yes, this will change depending on which recipe page you are on, which is what you want (I think).

Comment: ah that makes more sense now that ransack isnt being used. I will try it tonight and let you know how i get on. thanks again

Comment: oh i do have a question at this point if you dont mind, after map in the variable terms you are passing t through a block? would you mind explaining why we are doing this?

Comment: You mean this part: `.map { |t| "%#{t}%" }`? That's to add the `%` symbols on either side of each term, which in SQL terminology means "match anything that contains this string". So `["italian", "pasta"]` becomes `["%italian%", "%pasta%"]`.

Comment: p.s. I've moved the code to an instance method, which is the better place for it. Also I added a condition to exclude the recipe itself, so that you don't show the recipe in the list of related recipes.

Comment: wow thats really neat, thanks very much. any recommendations on some material to read to help understand methods like map, data manipulation, why we do it etc

Comment: For the Rails DB stuff, the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) guide is good. For `map`, etc. consult the Ruby Array documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map

Comment: Another good reference on Ruby is the Well-Grounded Rubyist: http://www.manning.com/black2/ Read it from cover to cover and you'll really understand Ruby well.

Comment: ok so im trying out the code and am getting  NoMethodError in RecipesController#show undefined method `dish_name' for nil:NilClass, going to look to see whats going on but any pointers appreciated

Comment: Sorry my mistake, this line: `terms = @recipe.dish_name.split(' ').map { |t| "%#{t}%" }` in the `related_recipes` method should be `terms = dish_name.split(' ').map { |t| "%#{t}%" }`. (There is no need to reference the instance `@recipe` because the method is called from the instance itself.)

Comment: Just tested the code and it should work, sorry about that slip.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, i thought it was because there was no dish_name that was similar, so no result. hence the nil class. Glad you spotted that one

Comment: off subject I know but hope all ok your end, just heard the news of quake hitting your area?

Comment: yes thanks for asking! I was actually on my bike and didn't notice until it had already passed, but I heard it was pretty big (and long).